# SwiftUI setting up external variables that will trigger a view refresh

Tags: swift, global-variables, swiftui, combine

iOS 13, Swift 5, Xcode 11.3.1

Learning SwiftUI. I put this together, and it works, but is it correct.

In **External.swift**

```
class BlobModel: ObservableObject {
  @Published var score: String = "" 
}

var globalBlob = BlobModel()
```

In **ContentView.swift**

```
struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var globalBlob:BlobModel

var body: some View {
  Text("\(globalBlob.score)")
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
      ContentView(globalBlob: globalBlob)
    }
}
```

When I write to the globalBlob in **External.swift** it updates the display.

```
globalBlob.score = backToString
```

But globalBlob is a global variable, which is surely poor coding practice. Is there a better way I should have done this?

Comment: Thanks for the environmental suggestion, but sadly since the class that is changing the globalModel here isn't a view, it doesn't work.

Comment: you maybe interested in the answer at: [Refreshing a SwiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57727478/refreshing-a-swiftui-list/57733708#57733708)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you access a Singleton instance from the class that is changing the score?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/cocoa_design_patterns/managing_a_shared_resource_using_a_singleton

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @ObservedObject var globalBlob: BlobModel = BlobModel.sharedInstance

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Button(action: {self.globalBlob.score = Int.random(in: 0...100).description}, label: {Text("update-score")})
            Text("\(globalBlob.score)")
        }
    }

}

class BlobModel: ObservableObject {
    static let sharedInstance = BlobModel()
    @Published var score: String = ""
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Comment: This is an even better solution.

Comment: you can use `var globalBlob: BlobModel = BlobModel.sharedInstance` anywhere to update the instance so the `View` can be updated