# Why are subviews displaying old data when binding objects from an array?

Tags: ios, swiftui

Whenever a user returns to a form sub-view after saving data through a binding variable, the form displays old data from before it was edited, and I cannot understand why.

I have an array of Face objects (technically Core Data entities) declared as a State variable in a parent NavigationView. I then loop through them to create NavigationLinks like this:

```
@State var formDieFaces: [Face] = [] // this gets initialized akin to the below (truncated)

...

let face1 = Face(entity: Face.entity(), insertInto: nil)        
self._formDieFaces = State(initialValue: [face1])

...

ForEach (formDieFaces.indices) { curIndex in
    NavigationLink(
        destination: FaceForm(self.$formDieFaces[curIndex]))
    ) {
        FaceRowView(faceToList: self.formDieFaces[curIndex])
    }
}
```

And in FaceForm, I receive the variable and "save" it as such:

```
@Binding var faceToEdit: Face
@State var formFaceText: String = String()

...

// in the form
TextField("Placeholder text", text: $formFaceText)

...

// on save, do the below
self.faceToEdit.text = self.formFaceText
```

What's weird is that on "saving" in FaceForm, the main NavigationView **does** update, and in that NavigationLink (FaceRowView) everything shows the correct data. But if I click back into FaceForm thereafter, it displays old data from before the save.

I have a feeling I'm doing something phenomenally obtuse with the State and Binding variables, but I just can't for the life of me figure out what's going on. I've tried various combinations of @ObservedObject, @ObservableObject, @StateObject, etc.

Could anyone please point me in the right direction?

*Edit: to be clear, FaceRowView works and displays the correct data. FaceForm is where the problem is occurring, almost like it's remembering an old copy of the data.*

If it's helpful, here is a link to a video of the behavior: https://youtu.be/8eC-TdtFP5s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those curious, I'm not 100% sure this is a pure, proper SwiftUI solution, but I found a hack/workaround on this page that I've implemented and seems to have "solved" the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57733708.